# I want my function to return a Stream[T], but I can't figure out how to make it type check

Tags: scala

I'm playing with some basic programming exercises in order to learn Scala better, but I'm stuck on trying to figure out why my code won't type check.

The sticking point is the `possibilities` function. I want a function which returns a stream containing all possible arrangements of numbers and math operators given a list of numbers.

I'm confused because changing the return type of the function to read `Stream[Object]` type-checks just fine and returns results that appear to be Streams of Equations. However, the version included below **does not** type check with the return type of `possibilites` set to `Stream[Equation]`.

As a side note, I understand that appending opsMix with cards doesn't put the `Operation`s in the correct order, but I'd like to solve this part of the problem first. I think I'll use `flatMap` or `zipAll` with `flatten` to accomplish that part.

Also - **this is not a homework assignment!**

```
abstract class Operation
case class Add() extends Operation
case class Subtract() extends Operation
case class Multiply() extends Operation
case class Divide() extends Operation
case class Num(val valu: Float) extends Operation

type Equation = List[Operation]

def calc(equa: Equation): Float =
  equa match {
    case Num(x) :: List() => x
    case Num(x) :: y :: Num(z) :: xs => y match {
      case Add() => calc( Num(x + z)::xs )
      case Subtract() => calc( Num(x - z)::xs )
      case Multiply() => calc( Num(x * z)::xs )
      case Divide() => calc( Num(x / z)::xs )
    }
    case _ => 0
  }

// from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070859/listing-combinations-with-repetitions-in-scala
def mycomb[T](n: Int, l: List[T]): List[List[T]] =
  n match {
    case 0 => List(List())
    case _ => for(el <- l;
              sl <- mycomb(n-1, l dropWhile { _ != el } ))
              yield el :: sl
}
def comb[T](n: Int, l: List[T]): List[List[T]] = mycomb(n, l.removeDuplicates)

val ops = List(Add, Subtract, Multiply, Divide)
def possibilities(cards: List[Num]) : Stream[Equation] =
  { for {
      hand <- cards.permutations
      opMix <- comb(cards.length-1, ops)
    } yield hand ++ opMix
  }.toStream

// test value:
val ppp = possibilities(List(Num(20), Num(3), Num(7), Num(100)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you declared your operation case classes as `Add()` etc., but in `val ops` you use just `List(Add, ...)`. If you try declaring `ops` with the correct type:

```
val ops: List[Operation] = List(Add, Subtract, Multiply, Divide)
```

you'll see the errors. (This is why it's often helpful to add types yourself instead of relying on the type checker - it helps to find errors.)

I suggest you to update your class hierarchy to use `case object` for singleton operations:

```
  abstract class Operation
  case object Add extends Operation
  case object Subtract extends Operation
  case object Multiply extends Operation
  case object Divide extends Operation
  case class Num(val valu: Float) extends Operation
```

Of course you'll need to update your patterns as well:

```
  def calc(equa: Equation): Float =
    equa match {
      case Num(x) :: List() => x
      case Num(x) :: y :: Num(z) :: xs => y match {
        case Add => calc( Num(x + z)::xs )
        case Subtract => calc( Num(x - z)::xs )
        case Multiply => calc( Num(x * z)::xs )
        case Divide => calc( Num(x / z)::xs )
      }
      case _ => 0
    }
```

Then `possibilities` works as expected without any changes.

Alternatively, you can keep the classes the way you have them, just change `ops` to

```
val ops: List[Operation] =
    List(Add(), Subtract(), Multiply(), Divide())
```

---

**Update:**
Concerning interleaving, you could do something like:

```
def interleave[T](xs: List[T], ys: List[T], padX: T, padY: T): List[T] =
  xs.zipAll(ys, padX, padY).flatMap(pair => List(pair._1, pair._2))
```

but note the result will always have an even number of elements. Perhaps a better solution would be to implement `interleave` yourself, something like:

```
def interleave[T](xs: List[T], ys: List[T]): List[T] = {
  import collection.mutable._;
  @annotation.tailrec
  def f(xs: List[T], ys: List[T], r: Buffer[T]): Buffer[T] =
    xs match {
      // By swapping the arguments, we get interelaving:
      case x :: xrest   => f(ys, xrest, r += x);
      case Nil          => r ++= ys;
    }
  return f(xs, ys, new ArrayBuffer[T]).toList;
}
```

However, I'd say that even better solution would be not to mix operations and numbers. Instead, you could declare a special class for well-formed expression formed from your symbols, something like (untested):

```
sealed abstract class Symbol
sealed abstract class Operation extends Symbol
case object Add Operation
case object Subtract extends Operation
case object Multiply extends Operation
case object Divide extends Operation
case class Num(val valu: Float) extends Symbol

sealed abstract class Expression;
case class App(val op: Operation, val arg1: Expression, val arg2: Expression)
  extends Expression;
case class Const(val n: Num)
  extends Expression;
```

and instead of creating an interleaved list, create an instance of `Expression`.

Comment: Thanks, nice answer. Your suggestions are totally correct. Now while trying to use zipAll and flatten as I had planned, I'm running into another type-related error... what would be your first idea for putting the `card`s and `opMix` items in interleaved order?

Comment: @DustMason I added some ideas to the answer.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! Your final suggestions feels more like the "scala way" to me since it solves the problem with well defined, typed classes.